# Multipart upload in amazon s3 not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, amazon-web-services

Trying to upload files bigger than 5 mb to Amazon S3

```
-(void)multipartUpload:(NSData*)imageData inBucket:(NSString*)bucket forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSLog(@"Coming");
    bool using3G = ![self isWifiAvailable];

    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
    @try {
        NSLog(@"Coming111");
        [s3 createBucketWithName:bucket];

        S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest *initReq = [[S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithKey:key inBucket:bucket];
        S3MultipartUpload *upload = [s3 initiateMultipartUpload:initReq].multipartUpload;
        S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest *compReq = [[S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];

        int numberOfParts = [self countParts:imageData];
        for ( int part = 0; part < numberOfParts; part++ ) {
            NSData *dataForPart = [self getPart:part fromData:imageData];

            // The S3UploadInputStream was deprecated after the release of iOS6.
            S3UploadInputStream *stream = [S3UploadInputStream inputStreamWithData:dataForPart];
            if ( using3G ) {
                // If connected via 3G "throttle" the stream.
                stream.delay = 0.2; // In seconds
                stream.packetSize = 16; // Number of 1K blocks
            }

            S3UploadPartRequest *upReq = [[S3UploadPartRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];
            upReq.partNumber = ( part + 1 );
            upReq.contentLength = [dataForPart length];
            upReq.stream = stream;

            S3UploadPartResponse *response = [s3 uploadPart:upReq];
            [compReq addPartWithPartNumber:( part + 1 ) withETag:response.etag];
        }

        [s3 completeMultipartUpload:compReq];
    }
    @catch ( AmazonServiceException *exception ) {
        NSLog( @"Multipart Upload Failed, Reason: %@", exception  );
    }
}

-(NSData*)getPart:(int)part fromData:(NSData*)fullData
{
    NSRange range;
    range.length = PART_SIZE;
    range.location = part * PART_SIZE;

    int maxByte = (part + 1) * PART_SIZE;
    if ( [fullData length] < maxByte ) {
        range.length = [fullData length] - range.location;
    }

    return [fullData subdataWithRange:range];
}

-(int)countParts:(NSData*)fullData
{
    int q = (int)([fullData length] / PART_SIZE);
    int r = (int)([fullData length] % PART_SIZE);

    return ( r == 0 ) ? q : q + 1;
}
```

Not uploading video. please help me.

Comment: Could you please share what version of the AWS iOS SDK you are using as well as any errors you receive?  You may also want to look into the S3TransferManager as it will handle larger file uploads using multipart upload. http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads